# Objective-C – Subclassing UITableViewCell, when to use layoutSubviews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When should `- (void)layoutSubviews` appropriately be used when subclassing a UITableViewCell. I noticed that I can place all my views and align them properly in the `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` without using `- (void)layoutSubviews`.

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call it directly in most cases. I think it gets called for you when the frame is changed (eg when a cell enters edit mode) but if you've set up your autoresizing masks appropriately, you don't need to do anything specific with or in that method.